# How to approach scheduled rules to real deathline?

Tags: 7, cron, rules

Hello Im facing a problem, I made an app that makes use of a lot of scheduled rules, I could notice that those rules are not executed exactly in the time that is indicated in the schedule, those rules executes with the CRON, so for example if the rule reaches the deathline it only is executed after run of CRON.

So I had to set the CRON to run more frequently but is there another way of make the rule executes exactly in the set deathline?

my app needs to be very accurate in the execution of those scheduled rules so that's why...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule scheduler works with CRON only so you have to run CRON frequently, but you can use [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module, where you can specify different schedule for different `hook_cron()`, so if you want your rules scheduler to run frequently then configure `rules_scheduler_cron()` to run say every five minutes and  configure other `hook_cron()` to run every two hours.

In that way you run reduce the load.

Comment: EXCELENT thank you did not know that Elysia cron module =)